# Java 8: Interface with single method

Tags: java

Sometime I need to make callback from one method to another:

```
final Integer i = 5;
final Integer j = 10;
foo("arg1", "arg2", (x, y) -> { 
    /** do sth which need this context **/ 
    bar(i + x, j - y);
})
```

But in such case I need to write simple interface (somewhere):

```
public interface someName {
    void noMatterName(Integer a, Integer c);
}
```

Then function `foo()` can call `noMatterName` - this is ok. But in simple cases, name of such interfaces and its function is not important. I just want to use lambda with two parameters.

**Question:**

Do I need to create this interface manually even if I need to make such "communication" between only *two* function? Does Java provide any similar interface?
Or even something like this:

```
public interface someName1 {
    void noMatterName(Object a);
}

public interface someName2 {
    void noMatterName(Object a, Object b);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Consumer<T>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) (if you need a single parameter), and [BiConsumer<T,U>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html) (if you need 2 parameters) functional interfaces.

> **Interface Consumer<T>**
>
> Represents an operation that accepts a single input argument and returns no result.
>
> **Interface BiConsumer<T,U>**
>
> Represents an operation that accepts two input arguments and returns no result.